# geom_text not labelling dodged geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can't seem to get geom_label to label a dodged bar plot by `CLASS` (the factor by which the plot is "dodged"). Rather, I am getting the total `count` per `PROC` (the `Y` axis):

```
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = PROC)) +
geom_bar(mapping = aes(fill = CLASS), position = "dodge") +
geom_text(stat = "count", aes(x = PROC, label = ..count..)) +
theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
    axis.text.x =  element_blank()) + 
scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap( 
    PROC.Labels, 
    width = 10)) +
coord_flip()
```

[image]

Additionally, I don't know why the 105 `geom_text` label is appearing so far to the right of this bar plot.

Comment: Please, provide a [mcve], preferably using `dput()`. This makes it much easier for others to answer your question. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to update `geom_text` to use the `position_dodge()` function. Here's an example, very similar to yours, using the built-in diamonds data set. I'm also using **ggplot** 3.0's `stat()` function, rather than the deprecated `..count..` variable.

Your labels appear far to the right because they represent the *total* count for each of your groups, and are thus placed at the corresponding higher (farther right) y position.

Note that providing `position_dodge()` a width value of 0.9 corresponds to the fact that by default, a categorical bar (or a dodged group of bars) takes up 90% of its available space on the axis, with the remaining 10% going to the margin between the bar groupings.

```
g <- ggplot(data = diamonds, aes(x = cut, fill = color)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge') +
  geom_text(stat = 'count', hjust = 0, position = position_dodge(0.9), aes(x = cut, label = stat(count))) +
  coord_flip()
print(g)
```

[image]