# Highlight one bar and label each with numbers while using fill

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

I'm trying to create a graph where I have an x, y and fill. I also want it to make the largest bar stand out more than the other. In addition I would like to label each bar by their mean revenue. However I'm running into a couple of issues.

code:

```
fruit <- df %>%
 filter(flavor == "FRUIT") %>%
   group_by(Promo_ad_both, Quarter) %>%
   summarise(avg_rev = mean(revenue)) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = Quarter, y = avg_rev, fill = reorder(Promo_ad_both, avg_rev))) +
geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
ggtitle("Fruit Average Revenue by Quarter",
      sub = "Fourth Quarter with a small ad and Promo is best performer") +
xlab("Quarterly Revenue by Promo/Ad group") +
ylab("Average Revenue") +
guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Promo and Ad type")) +
geom_text(aes(label= round(avg_rev, 0)), vjust=-0.2) +
theme_classic() +
coord_flip()
```

This is what it comes out as:

[image]

I want to make the purple bar in the 4th quarter stand out more. Does anyone have any suggestion to have to go about that?

Thank you!

Comment: Your text labeling issue is similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52618836/geom-text-not-labelling-dodged-geom-bar/52618916#52618916

Comment: As for making the largest bars stand out, you might consider mapping `Promo_ad_both ` to alpha, and mapping fill to something like `avg_rev == max(avg_rev)`.